# Attachments integration - REST

Tags: integration, rest

I have the following use case

**Opportunity O has five attachments namely (A1,A2,A3,A4,A5).
Each of these attachments are to be sent to different external REST webservices.**

In my experience previously, I have integrated object data via JSON deserializing/serializing and sending it to endpoints via HTTP calls.

But I am not sure how to send a file to an external webservice.

Is this even possible ?

Answer (score 1):

Use the SObject Blob Retrieve resource to retrieve blob data for a given record.

The following example retrieves the blob data for an Attachment record. The Attachment can be associated with a Case, Campaign, or other object that allows attachments.

Example for retrieving blob body for an Attachment record

```
curl https://na1.salesforce.com/services/data/v20.0/sobjects/Attachment/001D000000INjVe/body -H "Authorization: Bearer token"
```

**Attachment body content is returned in binary form. Note that the response content type will not be JSON or XML since the returned data is binary.**